# Is it possible to set a JMS listener destination at runtime with Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

We're using ActiveMQ in a Spring app and I'm setting up design that uses Virtual Topics based on the class name that defines the data being sent. So if I have a class

```
public class SomeEvent implements JmsEvent<SomeEvent> {
...
}
```

where `JmsEvent` is a helper interface for converting an implementing class into a `Message`, I have another class that will determine the destination name with a configurable override

```
public class DestinationNameHelper {
    private Map<Class<?>, String> overrides;
    ... 
    public String getDestinationName(Class<?> type) {
        return overrides.getOrDefault(type, type.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

This works fine for `JmsTemplate`, where the destination name is passed in for every message sent. I have a class that prepeneds `VirtualTopic.` to the result, so if you call `publisher.publish(someEvent)` the actual destination for sending `SomeEvent` would be `VirtualTopic.SomeEvent`.

What I'm trying to do is use the same type of things for listeners, so if I have

```
public class SomeEventListener extends BaseMessageListener<SomeEvent> {
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {}
}
```

I'd like to be able to automatically set it up to listen to the destination `Consumer.SomeEventListener.VirtualTopic.SomeEvent`, which right now is being typed manually into the XML config file.
Having the listener class name be overridable would be nice, but I would at least like to have the Virtual Topic name (i.e. `SomeEvent`) be retrieved through the `DestinationNameHelper` so the listener configuration doesn't have to change if we override a class' destination name.

E.g. if we add `(SomeEvent.class, "OverrideName")` to the override map in `DestinationNameHelper` the message for the class `SomeEvent` should publish on

```
VirtualTopic.OverrideName
```

And the listener should listen on

```
Consumer.SomeEventListener.VirtualTopic.OverrideName
```

I can't figure out the SPEL incantations to do this in XML configuration, and as the goal is to have destination names based on class names using the `JmsListenerConfigurer` is probably out of scope.

Is there a way to achieve my desired configuration?

[Edit]
My configuration looks something like this:

```
<bean id="someEventListenerBean" class="com.example.SomeEventListener"/>
<bean id="someEventListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.example.SomeEventListener"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="messageConverter">
        <null/>
    </property>
</bean>

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" acknowledge="transacted" concurrency="2-5">
    <jms:listener destination="Consumer.SomeEventListener.VirtualTopic.Somevent" ref="testListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Virtual Topics (while powerful) are unique to ActiveMQ 5.x so any application built around their functionality will be difficult, if not impossible, to port to another broker if the need arises. If would recommend using, if possible, a standardized solution like shared topic subscriptions from JMS 2.

Comment: Can you show your existing listener configuration - it will be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Even if we went to Artemis or another JMS provider, I'd still want to configure the listener destination dynamically. With shared durable topic subscriptions I'd still want something like `destination="#{destiationHelper.getDestinationName(SomeEvent.class)}"`.
I've also added a sample config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Justin and Gary for being rubber duckies. Clarifying and posting my configuration helped me come to an answer, though it could probably be optimized.

I modified the Listener interface to include

```
Class<T> getEventType();
```

so all implementing classes must return the class type of the even they're handling. I then created a class like

```
public class ListenerDestinationHelper {

    private final DestinationHelper destinationHelper;

    public ListenerDestinationHelper(DestinationHelper destinationHelper) {
        this.destinationHelper = destinationHelper;
    }

    public <E extends JmsEvent<E>, M extends Message, T extends JmsEventListener<E, M>> String getDestinationName(T listener) {
        final Class<E> eventClass = listener.getEventType();
        return "Consumer." + listener.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".VirtualTopic." + destinationNameFactory.getDestinationBaseName(eventClass);
    }

}
```

and now the configuration includes

```
<bean id="listenerDestinationHelper" class="com.example.ListenerDestinationHelper"/>

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" acknowledge="transacted" concurrency="2-5">
    <jms:listener destination="#{listenerDestinationHelper.getDestinationName(someEventListenerBean)}" ref="testListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

From here it would be trivial to add overrides for the listener class simple name

Comment: I played around with generics and now the generics in the actual code base are defined on the interface and class instead of the methods, but the gist is the same.